# Illegal concatenation of an unsized constant

Tags: concatenation, verilog, system-verilog

I wrote the following testbench:

```
// 4->1 multiplexer TB template
module mux4_tb;

//Some code

    initial begin
        d0={0,0,0,0};
    end

endmodule
```

But, when I run it, I get 24 errors like this one:

> Error (suppressible): mux4_tb.sv(23): (vlog-2121) Illegal concatenation of an unsized constant. Will treat it as a 32-bit value.

What's wrong with my code above?

In case you need it:

```
// 4->1 multiplexer template
module mux4 (
    input logic[3:0] d0,    // Data input 0
    input logic[3:0] d1,    // Data input 1
    input logic[3:0] d2,    // Data input 2
    input logic[3:0] d3,    // Data input 3
    input logic[1:0] sel,   // Select input
    output logic[3:0] z     // Output
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the concatenation operator in section 11.4.12 of the 1800-2017 LRM (or any earlier Verilog version), it says

> Unsized constant numbers shall not be allowed in concatenations.

This is because in earlier versions, the size of integers and integer constant literals was implementation dependent. But even now in the current version where an integer is sized 32 bits, many people forget that the simple unsized literals `0` and `0` are not single bits. They are implicitly `32’sd0`. (32-bit signed decimal literal 0) You would need to write the following to use a concatenation:

```
d0={1'b0,1'b0,1'b0,1'b0};
```

or you could just use a binary literal:

```
d0 = 4'b0_0_0_0;
```

Your mistake is exactly the motivation behind the restriction of not allowing unzied (actually *implictly* sized) literals inside a concatenation.

Comment: but why it's 32 bit? I wrote 0 for example and not 0 32 times

Comment: @albert because there is an implicit 32’sd in front of your literal 0. (32-bit signed decimal).

Answer (score 1):

`{0,0,0,0}` is a concatenation of four 32-bit values (according to the message) yielding a 128-bits of zeros. I guess you meant to concatenate 4 bits, which should look like this

`{1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0}`